# Setting timeout attribute in Doctrine / mysql PDO does not work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine, timeout

I'm trying to set a timeout for queries to my MySql database. I'm using Doctrine in Symfony normally, but even when creating a plain PDO connection it's not working. I've already seen several suggestions from older posts but nothing works. I try to do this right now

```
    ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 2);
    ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout',1);
    $conn1 = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=main',
        'root',
        'root',
        [
            0 => 5,
            PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ]
    );

    $conn1->exec("select sleep(10)");
```

I'm using MySql 8.0.35 and PHP 8.0.28